# Distinct in CosmosDB via MongoDB API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am building a MERN-stack app that has a CosmosDB database on the backend with a collection with structure similar to the below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c22dd1d58e77e47ac6361ae"), 
    "company" : "Company 1", 
    "feature" : "Feature 1", 
    "date" : "2018-10-04"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c22ddcb58e77e47ac6361af"), 
    "company" : "Company 2", 
    "feature" : "Feature 1", 
    "date" : "2018-03-12"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c22ddfc58e77e47ac6361b0"), 
    "company" : "Company 2", 
    "feature" : "Feature 2", 
    "date" : "2018-11-13"
}
```

I need the API to serve a list of all the "company"s that have listed features.  Normally, if this were a SQL database it would be `SELECT DISTINCT company FROM features`, but when I try to execute the query `db.getCollection("features").distinct("company")`, I get:

```
[js] Error: distinct failed: {
"_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 115,
"errmsg" : "Command is not supported",
"$err" : "Command is not supported"
}
```

In doing some research, it appears that CosmosDB was originally shipped without the ability to do a DISTINCT, but was added earlier this year.  Is there a reason this is failing, or is there a different way I can get the results of the query, or do I need to pull all the data and then de-dupe it in my program logic?

Comment: Not all MongoDB commands are implemented with Cosmos DB's MongoDB PI. According to documentation, `distinct` is implemented in the aggregation pipeline - have you tried using that?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Is there a special syntax for aggregation pipeline?  I'm not sure how to leverage it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Use Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB support for MongoDB features and syntax > Aggregation pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#aggregation-pipelinea), `distinct`, which is part of the aggregation pipeline, is only supported in public preview.

See [Azure #CosmosDB extends support for MongoDB aggregation pipeline, unique indexes, and more](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/) on how to onboard to the public preview.

Hope it helps!